# Using COM4J to create excel file

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, nullpointerexception, com4j

I am receiving a null pointer exception when trying to launch an instance of excel to export data to. I have tried adding the newest version of COM4J.jar to my netbeans project. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to find what the problem with it may be.

It seems to break on this line,

`excelApp = Microsoft.Excel.ClassFactory.createApplication();`

and outputs the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Microsoft.Excel.ClassFactory.createApplication(ClassFactory.java:89)
    at com.pmiapp.common.ExcelComWrapper.openExcel(ExcelComWrapper.java:37)
    at com.pmiapp.dmpc.Report.jMenuItemSaveToFileActionPerformed(Report.java:661)
    at com.pmiapp.dmpc.Report.access$300(Report.java:118)
    at com.pmiapp.dmpc.Report$7.actionPerformed(Report.java:559)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com4j.COM4J.loadNativeLibrary(COM4J.java:566)
    at com4j.COM4J.<clinit>(COM4J.java:522)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you need to init that library somehow? As you're invoking a method with no arguments on a chain of static classes (or at least it seems so) and the NPE is coming from the `COM4J` library itself.

Comment: After downloading the example Excel project that ships with Com4j and receiving the same problem with it, I've switched to Apache POI and am having a much better time.

Answer (score 0):

Up to date, to integrate *Microsoft Documents into Java*, you should start using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) instead of *com4j* or other forks.